# Do cards that increase battle point accumulation also increase xp gain?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

The `Bounty Hunter` star card is a battle point increasing star card for each of the four main classes:

[image: Bounty Hunter screenshot for officer]
The heavy also has an additional battle point increasing card, `Defender`:

[image: Heavy's defender card screenshot]

These cards can be nice when the player is trying to get points for another class or hero.  But I wonder: 'does this also increase the rate that experience points are gained?' That would make the cards more useful, because  otherwise a player might get experience points faster with other cards if these cards didn't count towards that value.

Do battlepoint increasing cards also improve the rate of experience point gain for the player and his current class?  Essentially do you receive experience points for all of the battle points you receive.  Or are the two values tracked separately and battle point cards do not impact player or class experience points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bounty Hunter only increases Battle Points.

### It does not affect Character or Career XP.

---

Here are the details of my test:

I started by recording my Career XP and my Specialist XP. Then I equipped a Rare (Level 3) Bounty Hunter card on my Specialist, and played a round of Galactic Assault. At the end of the game, I observed that I had earned a total of **3370 Battle Points**. (I didn't spend any on special units or heroes)

The End of Match screen however, only showed that I had earned a **Total Score of 2909**. When I got back to the Home screen, I checked my Career XP and Specialist XP. They both showed an increase of **2909 XP**.

---

You may notice that the math isn't quite right. The Rare Bounty Hunter card says that it gives a Battle Points Increase of 15%, and 3370 is closer to 16% (technically 15.8).

I'd speculate that the game calculates the 15% on each individual action that grants XP, and rounds that to the nearest integer for Battle Points. That would explain the seemingly large error in the end totals.